# Cannot get GPS location on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, gps, ios-simulator

My app runs perfectly on the simulator and everything works fine. But now i wanted to thest it on my iPhone and i found out that the GPS funcution don't work.

Here is my code.

```
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //eigener Standort
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    eigLat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    eigLon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    eigLatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", eigLat];
    eigLonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", eigLon];
}
```

And till now everything is fine. If i use NSLog i get the right coordinates.

But then i want to use my coordinates here:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];

    for (x=0; x<[news count]; x++)
    {
        //Berechnung der Entfernung
        erdradius = 6371.1;

        //Koordinaten von Datenbank in String schreiben
        NSString *latitude = [[news objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
        NSString *longitude = [[news objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"Longitude"];

        entfernung = 0;
        double lat1 = eigLat;                   //eigener Standort Latitude
        double long1 = eigLon;                  //eigener Standort Longitude
        double lat2 = [latitude doubleValue];   //Standort Heurigen Latitude
        double long2 = [longitude doubleValue]; //Standort Heurigen Longitude
```

And there I get everytime 0 for lat1 and lat2. But only if I Run the App on the iPhone. On the Simulator it works fine.

Does someone know why this could be?

Comment: where is eigLat defined? (Its not a GPS problem, its a simple programming problem, Log output eigLat in didUpdateToLocation, this will work, on th ephone too.)

Comment: in the .h file as double

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings? In `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, where does `data` come from?

Comment: @Sebastian this is not th epoint, the problem is that lat1 / eigLat is 0; (strings came from JSON)

Comment: data is from my JSON; and its easier i think because i get as strings and then I convert it to double

Comment: @AlexWien right thats the problem. And its only on the iPhone

Comment: @dereflo post the code of the definition of eigLat and the objective-c class

Comment: Are you getting the correct response back from the server while on the iPhone?

Comment: @AlexWien: It might not be the problem. But the code posted is incomplete. It's always better to provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org)

Comment: And if you want to store numbers in an object, why not use `NSNumber`?

Comment: yes with the JSON data works everything fine. Only the GPS don't work

Comment: do you need the whole code? because these are only some peaces

Comment: @dereflo, no only less experienced need the whole code, see my answer, and look how you defined _eigValue

Comment: Ah i know you problem now

Comment: I also noticed that you are using the old locationDidUpdate method, there is a new one introduced in iOS6 you may wish to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you did not get yet a GPS location in real world, so 
your method `connectionDidFinishLoading()` is called before `didUpdateToLocation()` was called.
Therefoe eighValue is still 0.

Check first for valid lat and longitude:
if both are 0 then you did not get a location.

I think that you must change the logic of your program code,
you have to either

1) wait till you have a location, and then start the 
connection such that connectionDidFinishLoading is called after you have a GPS coordinate.

Or
2)  you store the coordinate result of the network connection, and calculate when you got your first coordinate

Comment: Oh roght, i have checked it with break points and thos is the problem. But when I rund the program with the simulator i first get the location. Do you have an idea how i can solve this problem?

Comment: one solution, wait with the connection till you got a GPS location. you can simulaze this on simulator too, if you stop gps sumulation, later you enable it.

Comment: ok, now i have put the foor-loop in the location mehtod. But the porlbme is, that at first i have only 0m and when i scrol on the bottom and then back to the top the distance is right. Can you help me to solve this problem?